# JSP return to previous page without confirmation

Tags: jsp

I'm working on jsp site and I've got the following problem:

Suppose there's a page called `www.mysite.com/edit`.
In that page there's forms, buttons, etc to edit something.
Suppose you fill some fields and now have to edit something more especific, that needs to be done on another page.

That's the problem, that other page has the same address, i.e. `www.mysite.com/edit`. So, when the user is done with that, I want to redirect him to the previous state of the page, i.e, with all the previous forms still filled. And then, the user can confirm the editing and go to other page.

To redirect the user to the previous page I created a button with the folowing code:

```
<input type=button value="Back" onCLick="history.back()">
```

But this prompt a message telling if you want to resend the information back to the server. Is there a way to do that **without** prompt the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that without storing the state in the session along with an unique identifier and pass that identifier along as hidden input field of the form and submit the form instead of going back in history.

I suggest to rather do that "something more specific" in a JavaScript popup/overlay dialog which is opened while the parent page is still kept open.